# How to pass another command after executing script -a?

Tags: bash, logging, ssh

I am writing a bash script that will execute

```
script -a logfile.log
```

How can I pass another command to the new shell that is spawned by script? For example I would like to SSH to a host after this is executed so that my SSH session will be recorded by script. I tried this:

```
script -a logfile.log | ssh hosname
```

the following error occurs:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
script -a logfile.log -c some-command
```

Check out the manual page for `script` for additional options.

In your particular example, this might be what you're looking for:

```
script -a logfile.log -c ssh -t host run-something-else
```

Comment: While that is definitely the correct way to do it, I don't think it will get rid of his warning.

Comment: @jordanm - His warning is a result of having the stdin of ssh connected to the stdout of screen via pipe. The warning will not be present in the command line I proposed (ssh's stdin will be connected to the tty it's running in). The -T option to ssh could still be used (instead of the -t) if the ultimate program expects no input whatsoever.

Comment: unfortunately the -c option does not work in the version of Solaris that is running on the box I'm using

Answer (score 0):

That warning can be ignored, but the -T option should get rid of it.

script -a logfile.log | ssh -T hosname

Comment: This does get rid of the warning however when I try to authenticate with my password I am unable to login properly.  The remote device seems like it is not taking the input for some reason I can press return and my login fails.  I have attempted this multiple times to ensure I am not fat fingering the password to no avail.

Comment: @MarkScrano Have you considered using a RSA key for authentication? Otherwise, I would just ignore the warning.

Comment: unfortunately the devices I'm SSHing into are Alcatel routers and we have about 200 of them deployed in the network and they all use a TACACS authentication, I don't believe they have support for RSA keys although it would make my job much easier :-)